# MacOS C++ terminal compile shortcut?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I'm new to both C++ and using terminal on MacOS, and I was wondering if there's any way to make a shortcut for compiling.

It's somewhat annoying to have to type `g++ filename.cpp -o 'filename'` every time I want to compile. Just curious if there's anyway I could make a short cut where I just type `g++ 'filename'`.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile). You set it up once and then run `make filename`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. appreciate it

Comment: For toy programs, I have a script that I call. For bigger projects, I go the cmake route.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a Makefile (or another build system) to compile your code. Maybe check out the following thread for some insight on how C++ projects are usually built: [Difference between Cmake, gnu make and manually compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221869/difference-between-cmake-gnu-make-and-manually-compiling)

However, if you know that you'll write single file scripts, then maybe the [following bash file approach from this SO thread would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768931/bash-script-to-compile-and-run-c-program):

For easy access, this was the code example provided by @Some programmer dude:

> ```
> output=$(g++ $PROG_NAME 2>&1)
> if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
>     # There was an error, display the error in $output
>     echo -e "Error:\n$output"
> else
>     # Compilation successfull
>     ./a.out
> fi
> ```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like makefiles are definitely something I should get used to